# When replying to a page via FB API the message is blank

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to reply to a page via the Facebook API.

I can reply to the page via the Graph API. Have Application up the top right set to my App. Get my page token, enter `"/{conversation-id}/messages"`, switch to POST, Click Add field, then a add key value pair - "message" "this is my message", click submit and it works, the message appears in the chat.

When I try to reply via my app, it appears to go through, I get no errors and the uuid of the message is returned to me once it has been submitted. It does not appear in the chat, I either get my page icon, like sending an empty message, or I get a message

> "Attachment Unavailable This attachment may have been removed or the
>   person who shared it may not..."

If I take the uuid of the message and check on the Graph API, I can see that the message was indeed created, but the "message" field is empty, like it was stripped out.

The code I am using in my app:

```
  postMessage: function($scope, pageToken, thread, message){
    FB.api("/"+ thread +"/messages", "POST", {"message": "message"},
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
           console.log("Success")
        }else{
           console.log("failed")
        }
      }, {access_token: pageToken}
    );
  }
```

Not sure why this is happening and I couldn't find anything online about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was a simple oversight on my part, I needed to pass the access_token in just after the POST, rather than at the bottom of the function.

```
 postMessage: function($scope, pageToken, thread, message){
    FB.api("/"+ thread +"/messages", "POST", {"access_token": pageToken, "message": "message"},
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
           console.log("Success")
        }else{
           console.log("failed")
        }
      }
    );
  }
```